# "cout formatting options to print out currency values." What does this mean and how can I do this?

Tags: c++, currency-formatting

I'm a beginner in programming and I've just started to learn C++. I was assigned to make a change calculator (calculating the amount of money given back after a purchase) for class and there was an extra credit option that I did not understand.

"Use the built in cout formatting options to print out currency values. You can also experiment with DOS based color coding for input and output displays. Use your favorite search engine on how to do this."

I've searched online and I cannot figure out what my professor wants, can anyone explain what I need to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you get the answers from us, then you're not doing the assignment. We're not a search engine.

Comment: @Barmar, I never requested anyone to do any work for me. This is an extra credit part of an assignment I already completed and I just wanted someone to clarify what I was supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about DOS coloring, but I think this is what your professor is referring to: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Michael Albers about cout currency.

DOS color codes could be referring to ANSI escape sequences:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php

They were available in DOS if you had a device driver installed that supported them.

If it is you can use them like this:

```
cout << "\x1B[31;40m"; //Sets red text on black background
```